# File.createTempFile() shows "Inapropriate blocking method call" in CoroutineWorker

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have the following class that implements `WorkManager`

```
@HiltWorker
class LexemeWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    companion object {
        const val Progress = "Progress"
        private const val delayDuration = 1L
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        val storageRef = firebaseStorage.reference

        val pathReference = storageRef.child("lexeme.zip")

        val file = File.createTempFile("lexeme", ".zip")

        val path = pathReference.getFile(file).await()

        var progress = 0.0

        while (progress < 100) {
            progress = (100.0 * path.bytesTransferred) / path.totalByteCount
            setProgress(workDataOf(Progress to progress))
            delay(delayDuration)

            if (path.error != null) {
                return Result.failure()
            }
        }
        
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

I don't know for whatever reason, the android studio is showing the message `"Inapropriate blocking method call"` on `createTempFile`. I have also tried to put everything inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` but without a chance of solving the problem. How to get rid of this warning?

Edit1: The other way around `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

    ....

    val file = File.createTempFile("lexeme", ".zip")

    ...

    while (progress < 100) {
        progress = (100.0 * path.bytesTransferred) / path.totalByteCount
        setProgress(workDataOf(Progress to progress))
        delay(delayDuration)

        if (path.error != null) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    Result.success()
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should execute that code in a thread? But why do you want to create a file already? Will not getFile(file) create the file. You only need to set up a File instance so getFile knows where to create the file.. Not to create a file already. Hm.. or is this File class from Firebase and not the classic java io File class?

Comment: "I have also tried to put everything inside withContext(Dispatchers.IO) but without a chance of solving the problem" -- that warning is overly-zealous. Still, I have not seen it show up when using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. Could you edit your question and show how you used it?

Comment: @CommonsWare edited my question. Thanks

Comment: That seems to be [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177458751).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this warning occurs, maybe because `File.createTempFile()` function throws `IOException`. To get rid of this warning we can wrap `File.createTempFile()` function into `runCatching`:

```
...

val file: File? = runCatching {
    File.createTempFile("lexeme", ".zip")
}.getOrNull()

...
```